# Create graph from a GIT repo

Tags: git, graph, diagram

How could I obtain the necessary information to create graphs attached in this post that would essentially give me the following visual.. 
COMMIT ID -> TREE ID -> BLOBS

[image: GIT Graph Img 1]

Here's another one..

[image: Img 2]

Comment: Basically what the images attached show. COMMIT ID -> TREE ID -> BLOB/TREE's

Comment: Yes, what sequences of GIT commands would I need to give me this relationship data that I could ideally import into a graphing application

Comment: Looking at the `git show` manpage, `git show --pretty=%t <commit>` will show you the tree associated with a commit. You can probably figure out similar ways to get the rest of the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem.  One is very easy: getting the graph edges and vertices out of Git.  The other is very hard: drawing a "pretty" (planar, with minimal line crossings) diagram.

You seem to be asking about the easy part, so here's the answer: use `git cat-file -p` to obtain the contents of each Git object, starting with some known Git hash ID or IDs.  (Use `git rev-parse` to obtain the initial IDs.)

For example:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
d35688db19c9ea97e9e2ce751dc7b47aee21636b
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree 242af4b1a902347da2ff144516fb40c4a28ca257
parent 43c9e7e365d7a8961767d0bd4a305ca378800a2a
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1507361343 +0900
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1507361343 +0900

Prepare for -rc1

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

(the `git cat-file` example here is meant to show that you can use *either* a symbolic name, *or* a hash ID, to get the process started).  Examining a commit object will get you exactly one `tree` line, and zero or more `parent` lines, providing the hash IDs for the parent edges (note that this is a DAG and these are outgoing arcs, if you care to draw arrow heads on your edges).

A `tree` object has a relatively rigid internal form, which again can be viewed through `git cat-file -p`:

```
$ git cat-file -p 242af4b1a902347da2ff144516fb40c4a28ca257
100644 blob 611ab4750bd21e77d0fec41c8b2e115574c692ff    .clang-format
100644 blob 8ce9c6b8888fe6c12949d30e3e8b461cb67bb43f    .gitattributes
040000 tree 7ba15927519648dbc42b15e61739cbf5aeebf48b    .github
100644 blob 833ef3b0b783b8180d0dad1ce336713bddf09b26    .gitignore
100644 blob cbeebdab7a5e2c6afec338c3534930f569c90f63    .gitmodules
100644 blob ab85e0d16d6383b13954220a0b41202bd68d5d73    .mailmap
100644 blob fead995eddd15460b6be81e6a5f7c8f0648368ca    .travis.yml
100644 blob 8c85014a0a936892f6832c68e3db646b6f9d2ea2    .tsan-suppressions
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree 3957dfa63966e1efd20481ebd61311397a34e8ab    Documentation
100755 blob ab04c977be0cfdb6f282b7911d3fe630d5f70c65    GIT-VERSION-GEN
100644 blob ffb071e9f03a79a052beaa4372fa790ecbabbb7b    INSTALL
[more, snipped]
```

Each output line begins with a "mode", which is `040000` if the object with this name is itself another tree, or one of `100644` or `100755` if it is an ordinary file.  (There are two more modes, one for symbolic links, and one for a "gitlink", which is how Git stores the submodule hash ID for submodules.  See also https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py for instance.)  Following the encoded mode, `git cat-file -p` prints the underlying Git object type, then the hash ID, then a tab, and then the file name component under which the blob or sub-tree is to be extracted.

Each hash ID is unique, so if a hash ID occurs more than once, you have a shared sub-node.  This is the case for several of the blob objects in your example graphs.  Note that a top-level tree can be re-used as well.  For instance, if you have this commit series:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

where commit `C` is is made by a `git revert` of commit `B`, it's very likely that `A` and `C` use the same top-level tree (which automatically means they use all the same sub-trees and blobs).

Comment: I'd really like to know how to have git return me a format that is importable (likely csv) into some typing of graping application, visio.. maltego?

Comment: If all you want are the commits, it's not too hard: `git rev-list --parents` does most of the work. If you want to descend trees and blobs you will have to write your own code: adding `--objects` will print tree and blob IDs, but not their types. (For blobs you can *infer* the type by the presence of a path name, but this does not distinguish trees from parent-less commits.)

Comment: `git rev-list --parents --objects | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(rest)` is the way to get the snapshot structure fast, you still need to do the ls-tree's on the discovered trees to get the structure for the individual snapshots. (edit: I like your `git cat-file -p` better here, be kind and forget I said ls-tree)